# JavaScript Functions Running Randomly

Tags: javascript, function, threshold

I have a button, and a counter. The counter is assigned `count`. When you click the button `counterPlusElem`, the `count` increases. You can buy upgrades that take away some of your `count`, but make it so on each click of `counterPlusElem`, it adds 2 to `count` instead of 1. The `background-image` property changes once a certain `count` threshold has been met, or that's the goal. Once the image has changed from `car1.png` to `car2.png`, I don't want it to be able to switch back. The problem is that once you have enough `count`, you reach `car4.png`, then it starts reverting again.

Thanks.

Code :

```
function levelUp() {
        if (count >= 0 && count < 10) {
            imageCount1++;
            console.log("imageCount1 + 1");
        }
        if (imageCount1 > 0 && imageCount2 < 1) {
            counterPlusElem.style.backgroundImage = "url('car1.png')";
            imageCount2 = 0; // Reset other image counts
            imageCount3 = 0;
            imageCount4 = 0;
            imageCount5 = 0;
            imageCount6 = 0;
            imageCount7 = 0;
        }

        if (count >= 10 && count < 100) {
            imageCount2++;
            console.log("imageCount2 + 1");
        }
        if (imageCount2 > 0 && imageCount3 < 1) {
            counterPlusElem.style.backgroundImage = "url('car2.png')";
            imageCount1 = 0; // Reset other image counts
            imageCount3 = 0;
            imageCount4 = 0;
            imageCount5 = 0;
            imageCount6 = 0;
            imageCount7 = 0;
        }
        if (count >= 100 && count < 1000) {
            imageCount3++;
            console.log("imageCount3 + 1");
            imageCount2 = 0;
        }
        if (imageCount1 < 1 && imageCount2 < 1 && imageCount3 > 0 && imageCount4 < 1) {
            counterPlusElem.style.backgroundImage = "url('car3.png')";
            imageCount1 = 0; // Reset other image counts
            imageCount2 = 0;
            imageCount4 = 0;
            imageCount5 = 0;
            imageCount6 = 0;
            imageCount7 = 0;
        }
        if (count >= 1000 && count < 10000) {
            imageCount4++;
            console.log("imageCount4 + 1");
            imageCount3 = 0;
        }
        if (imageCount1 < 1 && imageCount2 < 1 && imageCount3 < 1 && imageCount4 > 0 && 
imageCount5 < 1) {
            counterPlusElem.style.backgroundImage = "url('car4.png')";
            imageCount1 = 0; // Reset other image counts
            imageCount2 = 0;
            imageCount3 = 0;
            imageCount5 = 0;
            imageCount6 = 0;
            imageCount7 = 0;
        }
        if (count >= 10000 && count < 50000) {
            imageCount5++;
            console.log("imageCount5 + 1");
            imageCount4 = 0;
        }
        if (imageCount1 < 1 && imageCount2 < 1 && imageCount3 < 1 && imageCount4 < 1 && 
imageCount5 > 0 && imageCount6 < 1) {
            counterPlusElem.style.backgroundImage = "url('car5.png')";
            imageCount1 = 0; // Reset other image counts
            imageCount2 = 0;
            imageCount3 = 0;
            imageCount4 = 0;
            imageCount6 = 0;
            imageCount7 = 0;
        }
        if (count >= 50000 && count < 100000) {
            console.log("imageCount6 + 1");
            imageCount6++;
            imageCount5 = 0;
        }
        if (imageCount1 < 1 && imageCount2 < 1 && imageCount3 < 1 && imageCount4 < 1 && 
imageCount5 < 1 && imageCount6 > 0 && imageCount7 < 1) {
            counterPlusElem.style.backgroundImage = "url('car6.png')";
            imageCount1 = 0; // Reset other image counts
            imageCount2 = 0;
            imageCount3 = 0;
            imageCount4 = 0;
            imageCount5 = 0;
            imageCount7 = 0;
        }
        if (count >= 100000 && count < 200000) {
            imageCount7++;
            console.log("imageCount7 + 1");
            imageCount6 = 0;
        }
        if (imageCount1 < 1 && imageCount2 < 1 && imageCount3 < 1 && imageCount4 < 1 && 
imageCount5 < 1 && imageCount6 < 1 && imageCount7 > 0) {
            counterPlusElem.style.backgroundImage = "url('car7.png')";
            imageCount1 = 0; // Reset other image counts
            imageCount2 = 0;
            imageCount3 = 0;
            imageCount4 = 0;
            imageCount5 = 0;
            imageCount6 = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I apologize if this isn't enough, or too much code. Also thank you so much for helping.

Comment: *each click of counterPlusElem* ... what is "counterPlusElem"? are all your variables globally defined somewhere else? An which *functions* are *running randomly* - you've shown one function, at there's nothing random in nature about it

Comment: counterPlusElem is the button that adds to count. My variables are all defined. The function I have shown above is supposed to change the background-image property of counterPlusElem without it reverting to the previous image, it is randomly reverting to the previous image and I'm not sure why.

Comment: I'd add some console.log's to see what the value of each of those `imageCountN` variables is every time you enter that function (and again when you leave) just to see what's happening. I find the code hard to read, and the logic seems inconsistent (but that be be a function of readability)